# Tune/Speed up Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, performance, aop, spring-aop

I am extending an application with a little bit of Spring AOP. What it does is retrieving data from the database and mapping it to an object. This takes about 7-8 seconds for 10.000 entries. However, when simply adding AOP with only one aspect, it will suddenly take about 50 seconds. The performance of the application is very critical and so far I could not come up with any ideas on how to make it faster. I guess the creation of the proxy is slowing it down.

*Further Information*

The object for each entry is annotated with scope `@Scope(scopeName=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` and retrieved from the application context `E object = appCtx.getBean(clazz.getName(), clazz);` before filling it. Filling is done via reflections and a recursive method.

The aspect, is simply registered for all setters of some specific class and its subclasses `execution(public void <package>.<Class>+.set*(..))` and AOP is enabled via `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`

Comment: Well for each setter you now suddenly execute additional logic, also getting a bean from the context is heavier then `new Class()`. So in the end all the additional milli seconds will add up. Not for a single one but for 10000 entries it will add up.

Comment: I am aware of the fact, that it will get slower with all these aditional stuff but by the factor of 6-7x? I mean, the additional aspect logic isn't even executed during creation of the object. I am filling the object directly on the field via reflection. Loading/creating objects from/via application context is also not that bad. It is still about 7-8 sec if I only remove `@Aspect`.  Any ideas on how to tweak it anyways?

Comment: No as there won't be much you can do. You get a proxy, a proxy means overhead. Regardless the fact of reflection if there is a method call in place it needs to check the point cut if ti needs to be applied. If you want more speed use load or compile time weaving instead of proxies.

Comment: I agree with @M.Deinum, compile time or load time weaving would probably improve things a lot.

Comment: ok. so one possible solution would be to use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP and use some sort of weaving instead of proxies?

Comment: If the Spring AOP is causing your performance problem, AspectJ should give much better results as it happens at compile time / load time, while Spring AOP does it's job at object creation time by setting up the proxying. If the problem is caused by the job you do in the aspect itself, I won't expect much change.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try AspectJ and let you know the result.

Comment: After adding AspectJ it now completes its task within 7 sec and still having the ability of AOP. Perfect :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using AspectJ instead of Spring AOP did the trick. Now I have AOP functionality without any significant loss in performance.